# Updated my rust version but still getting this error

Tags: anchor, rust

this is my rustup version
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.68.0 (2c8cc3432 2023-03-06)

and this is my solana version
solana-cli 1.14.16 (src:0fb2ffda; feat:3488713414)

running anchor 0.27.0

```
error: package `time-macros v0.2.8` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.63.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev
```

also this is my cargo

```
[package]
name = "zero-copy"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
rust-version = "1.60"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "new123455"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []
test-bpf = []

[dependencies]
anchor-client = "0.27.0"
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
bytemuck = {version = "1.4.0", features = ["derive", "min_const_generics"]}

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "1.14.16"
```

Comment: The Solana CLI tools come bundled with a `rustc` compiler that can be used for on-chain programs. 1.14 still uses an old version of Rust unfortunately. You can try upgrading to 1.15, but I can't guarantee that it's a high enough version

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, was able to work around it by pinning winnow and time to a compatible version. Just add this to your Cargo.toml and remove it once you upgrade to solana 1.16:

```
time = "=0.3.19"
winnow = "=0.4.1"
```

The cargo build-sbf command for solana 1.14 still uses rustc 1.62 that's why upgrading your system installation of rustc doesn't help in this case.